# Procrustes Problem With Scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, procrustes-problem

Given matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$, the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) asks to find an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that

$$\|AQ - B\|_F^2$$

is minimized. There is a simple closed-form solution to this problem.

I am interested in a variant of this problem where we would like to find both an orthogonal matrix $Q$ as before and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that

$$\|\Lambda AQ - B\|_F^2$$

is minimized.

Is this a known problem with a closed-form solution? It is basically matching two sets of points where a single rotation on one set and individual scaling on each point in that set is allowed.

Comment: If the diagonal matrix is taken to be a multiple of the identity, then [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4617344/81360) applies

Comment: Thanks. This case doesn't apply to the particular problem I am interested in unfortunately. I am specifically considering the case where $\Lambda$ has entries +1 and -1.